# GraphQL mutation not being sent to request when using Apollo client?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

I had an issue where I couldn't specify *URI* when sending custom headers to my backend server with `{ ApolloClient }` from **'apollo-boost'**,
So I had to use `{ ApolloClient }` from **'apollo-client'** instead.

---

That issue was fixed, but now my mutations aren't being sent to the backend?

My mutation :

```
import { gql } from 'apollo-boost';

export const LOGIN_USER = gql`
  mutation($email: String!, $password: String!) {
    loginUser(email: $email, password: $password) {
      userId
      token
      expiresIn
    }
  }
`
```

```
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import { setContext } from 'apollo-link-context';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';

const httpLink = new HttpLink({
  uri: 'http://localhost:3001/graphql'
})

const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
  const store = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('interdevs-data'));
  const token = store.token;

  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : "",
    }
  }
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});
```

```
  const login = async (email, password) => {
    try {
        const user = await loginUser({
          variables: {
            email,
            password
          }
        });
        const { userId, token, expiresIn } = user.data.loginUser;

        setUserData({
          token: token,
          userId: userId,
          expiresIn: expiresIn
        });

        sessionStorage.setItem('interdevs-data', JSON.stringify({ 
          "token": token, 
          "userId": userId, 
          "expiresIn": expiresIn 
        }));
    } catch(err) {
      console.log('login error: ', err);
      setLoginErr(err);
    };
  };
```

This is the error I'm getting.

```
"Error: Network error: Cannot read property 'token' of null"
```

When I switch it back importing ApolloClient from apollo-boost it works again.

---

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure, but I think the error lies here:

```js
const store = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('interdevs-data'));
const token = store.token;
```

If there are no items with the key `interdevs-data`, **store will be null**.

I think you can fix it by doing this:

```js
const store = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('interdevs-data'));
const token = store ? store.token : null;
```

Comment: oh thanks thats great, i'll add that to my code.

but its returning null because a token isn't being returned by the mutation, which is my main issue

Answer (score 0):

found out how to set auth headers with apollo-boost

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'http://localhost:3001/graphql',
  request: operation => {
    const ssData = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('data'));
    operation.setContext({
      headers: {
        authorization: ssData ? `Bearer ${ssData.token}` : ''
      }
    });
   }
});
```